# Modify an attribute of a sidemenu page from a child page

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm currently trying to modify the basic menu template of Ionic2 to put a footer with a progress bar.
First of all, here is my code :

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Tests</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let t of tests" (click)="openPage(t)">
        {{t.title}} <img [src]="t.thumbnail">
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>

<ion-footer>
  <div id="progress" [style.width.%]="progress">&nbsp;</div>
  // ^ This is my progress bar with the 'progress' value as width percentage
</ion-footer>
```

In my Typescript file for this page, I've set this attribute :

```
public progress:number;
```

And in the constructor : `this.progress = 30;` To set it to 30% by default.
Here is the rendering : 
[image: My progress bar]

I'd like to be able to modify the progress value from another page (For exemple, on the screenshort, I'm on the 'Affichage' page. Can I even access a value of the menu in order to modify it ?)
I thought about using Ionic 2 events and subscribe to any change to modify the progress bar. Is there another way, or I'm obliged to use events ?
Thank in advance for any help :)

Comment: yes you can use events.. alternate would be setting the value in a provider and using rxjs Subject to get the updated value..I would say events is easier here

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. So events are the best solution ? I can't access the value from outside ?

Comment: not sure what you mean by _accessing from outside_..but events should work